# Meteor helper function reruns several times when using 'findOne'

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor, meteor-helper

Let's assume I have a collection called Books:

```
{
 title : "string",
 author : "string"
}
```

Let's take a look on following code:

```
Template.bookList.helpers({
    books: function() {
      console.log('meteor');
      return Posts.find();
    }
});
```

In this case the 'meteor' will be printed one time. But if I use `findOne` like this:

```
Template.bookItem.helpers({
    book: function() {
      console.log('meteor');
      return Posts.findOne({'title':'title of the book'});
    }
});
```

The 'meteor' will be printed several times (in some case two in some six).

Why's that !?

Comment: it's because `helpers` are reactive when ever data changes it will re-run the function :) you can do `return Posts.findOne({'title':'title of the book'}, {reactive: false});` to disable it.

Comment: I tried this. but still the result is the same.

Comment: I think your `book` template helper will be executed multiple times, because you have multiple documents in your `Books` collection and you are including the `bookItem` template with `{{#each books}} {{> bookItem}} {{/each}}`.

Comment: no I'm not using each here, if I use each I get the following error

`Uncaught Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.`

Comment: @distalx in case it's still re-runs look at the template level what causes the template to re-render? If it's not data change it's template re-render. Show us your template code. Also you can try do `console.log()` inside onRendered and see if it's also gets called multiple times?

Comment: this is my template 
`{{#if book}}
<p>{{book.title}} {{book.author}}</p>
{{/if}}`

Comment: @MarkUretsky Don't waste your time on it. I'm Just trying to understand this behavior. 
 Thanks both of you for give it a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{#with}}` to trigger the function?
Sometimes `{{#if}}` doesn't work at intend